# adding field values to textarea and joining

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and I am trying to create a 'filter` and when a user selects the values etc it adds in to a textarea.

Below is the form. For example a user could create something that looks like this and it show in the output text area

```
`company` = 'RedLight' AND `name` = 'John' AND `dog` = 'yes'
```

Basically at the moment i've got it to add the first part `company = redlight`

But not sure how to then make the add button work, where the can add more into the current output.

**HTML**

```
// field 
<select id = "fieldvalue" class = "form-control select3">
<option value ="company"> company </option>
<option value ="name"> name </option>
 <option value ="name"> name </option>
</select>

// operator field
<select id = "operatorvalue" class = "form-control select3">
<option value = "="> Is equal to </option>
<option value = "!="> Is not equal to </option>
<option value = "3"> Contains</option>
<option value = "4"> Does not contain</option>
<option value = "<"> Less than</option>
<option value = ">"> Greater than</option>
<option value = "<="> Equals or less than</option>
<option value = ">="> Equals or greater than</option>
</select>

// value field

<input id = "valuetext" type = "text" class = "form-control">

<textarea id ="output"> </textarea>

<button type = "submit" id ="andcondition"> ADD </button>

<button type = "submit" id ="addfiltertext"> WHERE </button>
```

**THE JS** the addfiltertext button just changes output to NaN

```
 $("#addfiltertext").click(function(){

    var field = $("#fieldvalue").val();
    var operator = $("#operatorvalue").val();
    var valuetext = $("#valuetext").val();



      $("#output").val("`" + field + "` " + operator + "'" + valuetext + "'");


  });



    $("#andcondition").click(function(){

      var currentoutput = $("#output").val();



        $("#output").val(+ currentoutput + " AND ");
    });
```

Comment: in .addfiltertext.click you replace output with a new value rather than appending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are resolving the output value wrong, you don't need the + in the beginning.

Do like this instead:

```
$("#addfiltertext").click(function() {

  var temp = ' ';

  var field = $("#fieldvalue").val();
  var operator = $("#operatorvalue").val();
  var valuetext = $("#valuetext").val();


  temp = $("#output").val();


  $("#output").val(temp + "'" + field + "' " + operator + " '" + valuetext + "'");


});



$("#andcondition").click(function() {


  var currentoutput = $("#output").val();


  $("#output").val(currentoutput + " AND ");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, However, when I click the submit button again, it clears it and puts in the new values, how can i make it when you click submit again it adds the new values to the exiting text?

Comment: Check may updated code. I added a temp variable to save your old "state", not the most beautiful solution but it works